# userTimeline on a vector of user names - twitteR

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using the `twitteR` package to get some data from twitter and analyze it.

I have a vector of twitter user names:

```
user_vec <- c("barackobama", "time", "nytimesworld", "wsj", "wsjd")
```

I want to get each user's timeline.

```
user_timeline <- userTimeline("barackobama", 100)
```

Now instead of running this for each user, I would like to pass the function using `sapply`

```
sapply(paste(user_vec, collapse=""), userTimeline, 100)
```

When I run this, I get the error:

> [1] "Not Found" Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, method,
>   ...) :    Error: Not Found

I tried looping too:

```
for(i in user_vec) {
  userTimeline(paste(i, collapse = ""), 5)
}
```

Is there a way I can get the user timelines without and got the exact same error message. What am I doing wrong and is there a way I can get the user's timelines without having to run the same code over and over?

Comment: `"barackobamatimenytimesworldwsjwsjd"` is what you are searching for when you use `paste(...,collapse="")` - just use `sapply(user_vec, userTimeline, 100)`

Comment: tried that - I get an error: `[1] "Not Found"
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, method, ...) : 
  Error: Not Found` . . .